# Why my SQL MERGE inside an EXECUTE BLOCK with doesn't work?

Tags: sql, merge, firebird

A table1 contains a list of ids. The goal is to check if inside a table3 (for each id from the table1) there is a row which contains this id. If not, I would like to insert a new row which contains a list of values.

I've tried to do it with this block:

```
SET TERM #;
EXECUTE block AS
DECLARE idA bigint;
DECLARE idB bigint;
BEGIN
FOR SELECT id_x, id_y FROM table1 inner join table2 on table1.column = 'random' into :idA, :idB
do
MERGE INTO table3 FCA USING (SELECT '1' AS TEST FROM RDB$DATABASE) R ON (table3.column1= :idA)
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (null, :idB, :idA)
END#
SET TERM;#
```

However, it doesn't work (the MERGE statement). Actually, I've tried with an INSERT INTO. It works, but as you can see, it's not what I want.

So, why the merge doesn't work?

Comment: Your use of merge is unconventional. You don't need that `execute block`, you can put that select of the `for select` in the `using` clause of the merge.

Comment: Do you mean I can do a loop in the using clause ? Because, I need to check if the value exists for each rows contained in the first table. @MarkRotteveel

Comment: You don't need to loop: the `MERGE` statement does all that for you. It will process each row produced by the statement in the `USING` clause and check it against the target table.

Comment: Marvellous. It works too! easier, cleaner @MarkRotteveel

Comment: `INSERT INTO. It works, but as you can see, it's not what I want.` why not ??? just do `for select ... where /* your usual filters */ and not ( /* here your MERGE-ON filters */ )` or even left join. `for with X as (SELECT id_x, id_y FROM table1 inner join table2 on table1.column = 'random') select id_x, id_y from x left join table3 on (table3.column1 = id_X) where table3.column1 is null do insert ...`

Comment: Yes, it's a lack of knowledge about SQL.

Comment: @AlexKTP since you seem French, maybe you'd somehow make beeline with Synopse mORMot community. They are about Pascal/SQLite rather than Java/Firebird, but they probably are experienced with SQL base concepts and you can talk in native language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MERGE is working as RIGHT JOIN. In your case join condition is always fulfilled so NOT MATCHED action is never performed.